# Convert Stl into numpy array

Tags: numpy, stl, numpy-stl

Is there way to convert the stl file content into a numpy array or a set of numpy arrays?

I know that I can always read stl as file and then assign variables, but I was wondering if there is an automated way!

Answer (score 2):

Try the numpy-stl package.

After doing `pip install numpy-stl`:

```
import numpy
from stl import mesh

# Using an existing stl file:
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('some_file.stl')
```

Comment: As I'm the author of the numpy-stl package, I've edited the answer to improve some example. This should be enough to help @marco further :)

Comment: Is there a way of converting .stl files to images using numpy-stl ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using trimesh for that.
Here is an example script:

```python
from trimesh import Trimesh
from trimesh import voxel
mesh = Trimesh()
mesh.vertices=vertices
mesh.faces=faces
array = voxel.VoxelMesh(mesh=mesh, pitch=1).matrix_solid
```